# "This branch is 6 commits ahead of original:master" but 0 changed files

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I am trying to resolve an issue with old commits persisting through new pull requests from my personal forked repo to the original repo. I am using the GitHub website, not command line.

When I look at the page for my personal forked repo, I see "This branch is 6 commits ahead of originalrepo:master." However, these commits have already all been incorporated into the original repo. When I click on "pull request" or "compare", I see "Showing 0 changed files with 0 additions and 0 deletions," which makes sense since these two repos are currently identical.

How do I remove these old commits via the GitHub website/GitHub desktop so they don't show up in each new pull request I make to the original repo?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include what the command `git reflog` shows?

Comment: Hi, I am only using the GitHub website and GitHub desktop application, not the command line. I'm not familiar with running git using the command line. Can this issue only be resolved through the command line?

Comment: The issue can probably be resolved in various ways, one of them being the command line. I'm not sure how/if the `git reflog` command can be replicated though using GitHub desktop. Perhaps it's time to look into using the command line for git troubleshooting, sooner (i.e. now) or later it'll be useful...